# ConfigurationBuilder using ByteArray instead of reading from file

Tags: spring, mule, mulesoft

I am trying to build `ConfigurationBuilder` using `SpringXmlConfigurationBuilderFactory`. This code works when I pass resources (like file with location). I am trying to build the `ConfigurationBuilder` using `ByteArray` instead of a file resource.

Working code:

`SpringXmlConfigurationBuilderFactory` is from : `org.mule.runtime.config.api.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilderFactory`

```
//configuration is the file path with file to be loaded

private ConfigurationBuilder createSpringXmlConfigurationBuilder(String configuration) throws ConfigurationException {
    String[] configurations = new String[]{configuration};
    ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = SpringXmlConfigurationBuilderFactory.createConfigurationBuilder(configurations, this.mainContext);
    return configurationBuilder;
}
```

Need help on this code:

```
//configurationXML contains the XML as String....

private ConfigurationBuilder createSpringXmlConfigurationBuilderFromXML(String contextName, String configurationXML) throws ConfigurationException {

    ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =  new SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder(new ByteArrayInputStream(configurationXML.getBytes()));
    return configurationBuilder;
}
```

Comment: Is this for Mule 3 or Mule 4? Please add more detail on why are you trying to do this.

Comment: This is in Mule 4 and the reason I am trying to do this is to add the config (XML Blob) dynamically to the Mule context.

Comment: SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder is an internal class. You should not be using it.  SpringXmlConfigurationBuilderFactory doesn't have methods that support any ByteArray arguments.